# How can the closure of $(1,7]$ in $(1,7]$ with subspace topology include $7$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be given the standard topology. Then the closure of $(1,7]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $[1,7]$.

Let $(1,7]$ be given the subspace topology. Then the closure of $(1,7]$ in $(1,7]$ is $$[1,7]\cap (1,7]=(1,7]$$ but I'm confused as to why this can include 7?

We're considering $(1,7]$ as the full space and looking for the points in $(1,7]$ for which any open ball around it contains some point in $(1,7]$, but how can we even define an open ball around $7$ as it will have points outside the space (which seems similar to centering a ball around $\infty$)? And if we can do that (maybe via some empty set logic) then why can't we do that at $1$ and say $1$ is in the closure too?

Comment: A topological space is always closed in itself. Where's the problem?

Comment: A set is open in the subspace topology on $X$ if it's the intersection of an open set in the parent topology with $X$.

Comment: Notice that $(1,7]$ is closed in it's subspace topology.

Comment: Balls around $7$ are of the form $(7-r,7]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just ignore the part of the ball that sticks out.  By definition of the subspace metric we just use $B_{(1,y]}(7,r) = \{x \in (1,7] : |x - 7| < r\} = (7-r, 7]$ for $r<6$. So instead of all points closer then $r$ to $7$ in all of the reals we just take those inside the subspace in question.

This corresponds to open sets in the subspace $Y$ of $X$ as sets of the form $O \cap Y$ for open $O$ (open in $X$). Outside the subspace the subspace "sees" no points, essentially.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I see your argument but why (still looking at it from the restricted metric space viewpoint rather than from the equivalent subspace topology one) would $1$ not be in the closure by the same logic? Any ball around $1$ (ignoring the points outside the space) contains some point in $(1,7]$?

Comment: @Alex.F $1$ is not a point of the subspace so we cannot take a ball around it in the subspace metric, only points in the subspace can be centres of balls. and points of closures for that matter: if $A \subseteq Y$ the closure of $A$ in the subspace metric/topology (they are equivalent ) is by definition a subset of $Y$ too. The points of $Y$ are "all that exist" as far as $Y$ is concerned.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you so much :)

Comment: @Alex.F Glad to help. It's good to come to grips with this, it's essential stuff later.

Answer (score 4):

An open ball in $(1,7]$ is of the form $(1,7]\cap (a,b)$ by definition of [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology). So for example the open ball $(1,7]\cap (2,8)=(2,7]$ in $(1,7]$ (a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$) includes $7$.

Comment: Thanks for this perspective, I overlooked it!